# WPF- Aligning content in an itemscontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scrollview, itemscontrol

I have an itemscontrol inside of a scroll viewer and as an element gets closer to the center of the screen, it gets larger. The problem is, while it gets larger, its top left corner is locked into place and it looks like this.

[image: Not what I want]

I want it to look like this, but I have no idea how to go about doing it.

[image: What I do want]

Edit: Added xaml info, please ask for C# if needed (I doubt it though)

```
<TextBlock Name="text2" Text="hello" Margin="0,15,0,-10"/>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"         Height="300" Name="Viewr" Canvas.Top="120" ScrollChanged="Viewr_ScrollChanged">
        <ItemsControl Name="viewrcontent">
            <Canvas Width="100" Height="100" Background="Red"/>
            <Canvas Width="100" Height="100" Background="Red"/>
            <Canvas Width="100" Height="100" Background="Red"/>
            <Canvas Width="100" Height="100" Background="Red"/>
            <Canvas Width="100" Height="100" Background="Orange" Name="hellobox"/>
            <Canvas Width="100" Height="100" Background="Green" Name="midbox"/>
            <Canvas Width="100" Height="100" Background="Black"/>
            <Canvas Width="100" Height="100" Background="Red"/>
            <Canvas Width="100" Height="100" Background="Red"/>
            <Canvas Width="100" Height="100" Background="Red"/>
            <Canvas Width="100" Height="100" Background="Red"/>
            <Canvas Width="100" Height="100" Background="Black"/>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" Value="5"/>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" CanHorizontallyScroll="True"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: can you post your xaml?

Comment: what does Viewr_ScrollChanged do?  i assume that is what changes the green item?  the xaml you provided scrolls fine for me, but the center item doesn't increase is size or anything, is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: yes, when Viewr_ScrollChanged is called is when I resize the green item. As shown in the first image, I am able to resize the canvas, but what I can't do is center it so it doesn't look ugly. I can implement Canvas.Z property, but I don't know how to center the element.

Comment: If you apply a `ScaleTransform` as a `RenderTransform` to scale the items, you can set `RenderTransformOrigin` to `0.5,0.5`, which will force the items to scale around their center.

Comment: is only the green item supposed to resize or is it supposed to be the center item?  and is it supposed to shrink back down after you scroll away from center or what?  can you post your code behind?

Comment: @MikeStrobel that totally worked for me. Thank you, you're a life saver, I probably wouldn't have ever figured that out.

Comment: @Nivert9 can you post the working code behind, i'm interested.  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you apply a `ScaleTransform` as a `RenderTransform` to scale the items, you can set `RenderTransformOrigin` to `0.5,0.5`, which will force the items to scale around their center.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can edit the margin in the code-behind to get the desired behaviour. Something like this could work:

```
midbox.Width += 10;
midbox.Height += 10;
midbox.Margin = new Thickness(midbox.Margin.Left - 5, midbox.Margin.Top, midbox.Margin.Right - 5, midbox.Margin.Bottom);
```